What is actually critical point of function called?
Find the critical point of $\frac{x^2}{3-x}$ ?
I got a silly doubt please clear my doubt.

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{(3-x)2x+x^2}{(3-x)^2}=0$

$x(6-x)=0$ so critical point should be 0 and 6 right? cuz I send denominator to left side as square is always positive

So my doubt is that critical point of function is 3 or not? if yes then my question is function is not defined at 3.it means "3" is not in domain so why should we consider that point as a critical point?.

No shouting around here, please.

I think most reasonable definitions of a critical point don't apply to points where $f$ is not continuous or does not have a natural continuous extension

By the usual definition, a critical point of a function $f$ of one variable is a point in the domain of the function where $f'$ is either $0$ or undefined.  Since $3$ is not in the domain, it can't be a critical point.

We say the function $f : A \to B$ (with $A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$) has a critical point at $a \in A$ if either:

$f'(a) = 0$
$f'(a)$ does not exist

With this framing, there is an implicit third condition:

$a$ is in the domain of $f$

(This arises since we only consider the derivative $f'$ to have the same domain as $f$, or a subset thereof, i.e. we may exclude points but never add them, i.e. $\operatorname{domain}(f') \subseteq \operatorname{domain}(f)$.)
This coincides with the definition of critical point as on Wikipedia, and is the usual one in my experience.
In your case, then: $3$ is not a critical point of your function, since while $f'(3)$ is not defined, $f(3)$ isn't either. (You can also make the argument that it's possible that the derivative might be different than described by that function at $x=3$, so you should use the limit definition to be properly sure.)
So, some examples:

$$\begin{align*}
f : \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} &\to \mathbb{R} \\
x &\mapsto f(x) := \frac 1 x 
\end{align*}$$
This function has no critical points. It is differentiable on its entire domain, with
$$\begin{align*}
f' : \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} &\to \mathbb{R} \\
x &\mapsto f'(x) = - \frac{1}{x^2} 
\end{align*}$$
The derivative clearly does not exist at $0$. However, $f$ itself does not have a defined value at $0$, so it is not a critical point.

$$\begin{align*}
f : \mathbb{R}  &\to \mathbb{R} \\
x &\mapsto f(x) := |x|
\end{align*}$$
This function does have a critical point, at $x=0$. It is easy to show that
$$\begin{align*}
f' : \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} &\to \mathbb{R} \\
x &\mapsto f'(x) = \operatorname{sign}(x) := \begin{cases}
+1, & x > 0 \\
-1, & x < 0 \end{cases}
\end{align*}$$
by, e.g., the limit definition of the derivative. But what about at $x=0$, i.e. is the function $f$ differentiable at $0$? (The function $f$ is defined at zero, so we do need to consider the behavior at $x=0$.) You can show that this does not exist, also from the limit definition, making it a critical point.

$$\begin{align*}
f : \mathbb{R}  &\to \mathbb{R} \\
x &\mapsto f(x) := \sqrt[3]{x}
\end{align*}$$
Note that this function is still defined everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$. This one does still have a critical point as well, at $x=0$. The derivative is given by
$$\begin{align*}
f' : \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} &\to \mathbb{R} \\
x &\mapsto f'(x) = - \frac{1}{3} x^{-2/3} = - \frac{1}{3 \sqrt[3]{x^2}}
\end{align*}$$
We again ask, like before: why is zero a critical point? Why is zero not in the domain of $f'$? In this case, use the limit definition again to show that the limit there does not exist; hence, since $f(0)$ is defined, $0$ must be a critical point.
